# Boost.Interprocess v1.66 - get_bootstamp segfault with C#

Tags: c#, c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have problem with Boost.Interprocess (v1.66) library which I use in my C/C++ library which I use in C# through Marshalling (calling C native code from C#).

I found the problem if I was using Boost.Interprocess named_semaphore for sync between processes. (in open_or_create mode)

If I use my C/C++ lib with another native C/C++ code everything works fine (under newest Windows 10, Linux (4+ kernel) and even Mac OS X (>=10.11)). 
The problem occurred under Windows - with C# I have C wrapper around C++ code. If I use Marshalling with simple own-build EXE --> Everything works! But If I use The same C# code (with the same C lib) in the third party application as a DLL plugin I got segfault from get_bootstamp in named_semaphore.

So I have third-party C# SW for which I create plugins (C# DLL). In that plugin I use my C library through marshalling. Marshalling work fine in test C# project (which just call C functions from C lib) but same code segfault in third-party SW.

C Library workflow:

- Init all necessary C structures
- Start desired TCP server (native C/C++ app) using Boost.Process
- Wait for server (through named_semaphore) <-- segfault
- Connect to the server...

C# code has same workflow.

**Found the problem**

The problem occured in [boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::get_booststamp](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/9a605d3816a3ceadfedcc39efa4941d5ed5dfc43/include/boost/interprocess/detail/shared_dir_helpers.hpp#L40) (which is called in named_semaphore). here:

```
  struct windows_bootstamp
  {
     windows_bootstamp()
     {
        //Throw if bootstamp not available
        if(!winapi::get_last_bootup_time(stamp)){
           error_info err = system_error_code();
           throw interprocess_exception(err);
        }
     }
     //Use std::string. Even if this will be constructed in shared memory, all
     //modules/dlls are from this process so internal raw pointers to heap are always valid
     std::string stamp;
  };

  inline void get_bootstamp(std::string &s, bool add = false)
  {
     const windows_bootstamp &bootstamp = windows_intermodule_singleton<windows_bootstamp>::get();
     if(add){
        s += bootstamp.stamp;
     }
     else{
        s = bootstamp.stamp;
     }
  }
```

If I debug to the line

```
const windows_bootstamp &bootstamp = windows_intermodule_singleton<windows_bootstamp>::get()
```

booststamp.stamp is not readable. The size is set to 31, capacity is set to some weird value (like 19452345) and the data is not readable. If i step over to

```
s += bootstamp.stamp;
```

the segfault occured!

**Found the reason**

I debug once more and set debug point to the windows_bootstamp constructor entry and I got no hit so the stamp is not initialized (I guess).

**Confirmation**

If I change get_bootstamp to

```
  inline void get_bootstamp(std::string &s, bool add = false)
  {
     const windows_bootstamp &bootstamp = windows_intermodule_singleton<windows_bootstamp>::get();
     std::string stamp;
     winapi::get_last_bootup_time(stamp);
     if(add){
        s += stamp;
     }
     else{
        s = stamp;
     }
  }
```

Recompile my lib and exe - everything works fine (without any problem).

My question is - what I am doing wrong? I read Boost.Interprocess doc really thoroughly but there are no advice/warnings about my problem (yeah there is "[COM Initialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/interprocess/acknowledgements_notes.html#interprocess.acknowledgements_notes.notes_windows.notes_windows_com_init)" in Interprocess doc but it not seems helpfull).

Or it's just a bug in Boost.interprocess and I may report it to Boost bug tracker?

Notice - if I start server manually (before I run C# code) It works without segfaults

Comment: What's the purpose of the unused reference `bootstamp`?

Comment: It's a typo (in first code quote). Repaired. Thanks.

Comment: _if I start server manually (before I run C# code) It works without segfaults_ - permission problem?

Comment: I tried run third-party SW as an administrator. Same result. (If I run server manually I run it without special permissions. I just start powershell and run "./myserver <ip> <port>")

Comment: I created issue in Bost.Interprocess Github project - https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/issues/94

Comment: Should this question be closed out? It seems like it's a bug with a 3rd party library, and not necessarily an answerable question.